# Specifying limits of axes

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to limit x axis, i.e., frequency axis to 4 Hz in MatLab. This is the code I used:

```
        subplot(3,1,2);
        %Fse = 220;
        time = 0:1/fse:secBuffer-1/fse;
        %a = eegCounter;
        c = eegBuffer;
        wo = 50 / (1000/2);
        bw = wo / 60;
        [b,a] = iirnotch(wo,bw);
        y = filter(b,a,c);
        ydft = fft(c);
        xdft = fft(y);
        xlabel('Frequency');
        ylabel('Signal');
        xlim([1,4]);
        ylim([1,4]);
        plot(xdft,ydft);
```

However mine is live signal plotting and both x axis and y axis keep changing according to incoming packets. How to limit x axis to 4  Hz?

Comment: put the calls to xlim and ylim after the call to plot

Comment: so @brainReader did any answer help you solve your problem? If so please consider accepting one. Thanks!

Comment: @Benoit_11: Done. Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587967/finding-lag-between-2-signals-in-matlab

Comment: haha ok thanks for accepting mine :) I'll take a look at it later today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When plotting MATLAB automatically tries to fit the axis with the dynamic range of the data. Therefore if you want to make sure only a given range is plotted, you need to specify it AFTER the call to plot to force MATLAB to do it, otherwise it won't and you will be stuck with the whole data.

Here is a very simple code in which I call `xlim` either before or after the call to plot. See the difference?

```
clear
clc
close all

x = 1:50;
y = x.^2;

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
xlim([1 20])
plot(x,y)
title('xlim before call to plot')

subplot(1,2,2)
plot(x,y)
xlim([1 20])
title('xlim after call to plot')
```

Produces this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `XLimMode` (and `YLimMode`) properties of the axes to `manual`. But even if you do so every call to `plot(...)` will reset that to `auto` and mess up your axes limits.

The cleanest way is to first define your axes and your plots outside of any loop (not forgetting to get their handle), then when you update the data just update the `XData` and `YData` of the line objects, using the `set` method. The `set` method will only update the property you pass in parameters, so it will not modify the `XLimMode` property.

```
%// This part of the code should run only once
h.ax = subplot(3,1,2) ; %// get the handle of the axes
h.line = plot(0) ;    %// create an empty line plot
set(h.ax , 'XLimMode','manual' , 'XLim',[1 4]) ; %// define the properties of the axes (X)
set(h.ax , 'YLimMode','manual' , 'YLim',[1 4]) ; %// define the properties of the axes (Y)
xlabel('Frequency');
ylabel('Signal');
%//
%// This part of the code is the loop where you calculate and update your plot
%// ...
%// now do your calculations
%// ...
%// when it is time to update, just call:
set( h.line, 'XData',xdft 'YData',ydft ) ;
```

Comment: good one @Hoki I prefer your solution to mine, which is quite trivial. +1 :)

Comment: Excellent one... Worked smoothly, however it runs only once. So I'd work around it.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni. You should run the top part only once, but the 'refresh' part you run it as many time as you need. There is no trace of a loop (or any _live_ refresh) in your example code, so I couldn't replicate it. I don't know how your data get refreshed, but every time they do just call the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function axis as defined there [axis function matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-axis-limits-of-graph.html)